# When subclassing NSCoder, would I need to subclass collection classes (i.e:NSArray,NSDictionary) aswell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscoding, nscoder

I'm exploring the idea of subclassing [`NSCoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/subclassing.html) to read/write a proprietary file format.  I'm starting to believe this might also require me to subclass `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` to override `encodeWithCoder:` to ensure they are encoded properly:

```c
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    if ([encoder isKindOfClass:[CustomCoder class]]) {
        // call [encoder encode...] as I see fit.
    }else
        [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
}
```

I'm reluctant to do this because `NSCoder` and its related protocols `NSCoding` should be self-sufficient... Requiring subclassing classes following the protocol seems like bad design.  Am I missunderstanding or over-thinking something?!?

**Elaborating a little:**
For example, if the file format stipulates that lists of items are encoded like so:

```
...      // rest of file
0xA1     // marks the beginning of a list
0x0010   // amount of item in list.  The list contains 16 items in this example.
...      // encoded items follows
```

I would imagine that to encode an array, it's `encodeWithCoder:` would need to look like this:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(short) at:&itemCount];
    for ( /*for each item of the array*/ ) {
        [item encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    }
}
```

Because I ignore how NSArray's `encodeWithCoder:` is implement, I imagine I'd have to override it to use my NSCoder class properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why do you think you need to subclass collection classes. How your implementation will differ from default one?

At some point `encodeObject:` method of your `NSCoder` subclass will get called. In that method you can recognize `NSArray` and encode it as your format requires.  I mean it's up to your `NSCoder` subclass to call `encodeWithCoder:` of objects it encounters or not to call and encode them somehow else.

Comment: Elaborated the question a bit. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: At some point encodeObject: method of your NSCoder subclass will get called. In that method you can recognize NSArray and encode it as your format requires.

Comment: I mean it's up to your NSCoder subclass to call encodeWithCoder: of objects it encounters or not to call and encode them somehow else.

Comment: Very interresting!! But if I had myClass to encode with NSKeyedArchiver, the myClass's `encodeWithCoder:` would [describe itself](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html) to NSKeyedArchiver (by calling things such as `encodeFloat:forKey:`). But with a custom NSCoder, you say it's the other way around?!? The coder is aware of how to encode particular classes. Interesting to have the _model describing itself to the coder_ in one scenario and _the coder being aware of the model_ in another. Do I understand this right?

Comment: `NSCoding` protocol with its `encodeWithCoder:` method allows coders to encode any object without knowing anything about it. But it doesn't mean coder MUST use `encodeWithCoder:` for all objects. So for all objects except `NSArray`s you can call `encodeWithCoder:` like standard coders do but for `NSArray`s write header, length and then call `encodeWithCoder:` for all objects of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for you, you will not need to subclass any collection classes such as `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. This is because of the magic of polymorphism, the idea that the collection will encode each object individually by calling `encodeWithCoder:` on it. Because of this, simply implementing the `NSCoder` protocol on a class will be sufficient for encoding a collection that may contain instances of that class.

Comment: But if an encoded array must look like : _<8bit-Constant><16bit-ITEM-COUNT><ENCODED-ITEMS>_ (see question for the added example). How do you ensure this encoding solely with an NSCoder without subclassing NSArray?